# Bind number key (numeric keypad)

Tags: input, event-handling, tcl, keypad

I'm trying to make a fancy calculator (using button widget).

It necessary input numberkey (like 1,2,3 or num1,num2).

So i tried like this

```
bind . <key 1> {multiply $numberKey}
```

or

```
bind . <1> {multiply $numberKey}
```

But it's not working.

how can i bind the numeric key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the <kbd>1</kbd> key is `1`, *without* `<…>` around it.

```
bind . 1 {puts "pressed one"}
```

You can also use the *full* name, which needs to be described as a `KeyPress` event (which you can shorten to `Key` if you want):

```
bind . <KeyPress-1> {puts "pressed one"}
```

To get the name of an arbitrary key, try this little script:

```
bind . <KeyPress> {puts "pressed %K (producing character %A)"}
```

That prints the name of the key (what you need with a `KeyPress` prefix as a description) when you press the key. Single character keysyms can be used directly, but numbers cannot be just put in `<…>` because that's special cased to mean mouse button presses instead (as those are more commonly bound to specifically in most applications).